# I didn't add yeast nutrients to my cider is this going to be a problem?

Tags: cider, yeast-nutrient

So I didn't put any yeast nutrient into my cider and I was wondering if this is going to be a problem? I put in EC-1118 yeast packet into a 5 gallon carboy of juice. I have never made cider before and really don't want to mess this up. Also how critical is a hydrometer...

Answer (score 4):

I never use nutrient in my ciders and they turn out great.

You don’t need a hydrometer either. It can be useful but is not essential.

Cidermaking can be as simple or as complex as you want it to be. There is no wrong way to do it. Don’t let anyone tell you otherwise.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks man! That was just the answer I was hoping for not to complicated and super intuitive. I appreciate you taking the time to answer dmtaylor.

Comment: If you like my answer, I'll accept an up-vote.  :)

Comment: I agree, except with some high gravity ferments.

Answer (score 0):

I have only had issues with cider ferments when I add extraneous sugars to raise the gravity.  And I mean a significant amount of honey, brown sugar or the like.  In those examples a little yeast nutrient tends to keep the yeast going strong a little deeper into completing the task as the %ABV goes up.  Otherwise, straight cider doesn't require extra nutrients.

As for the hydrometer, if you don't want to know the numbers for calculating ABV its no big deal to have one.  I just make sure fermentation is done before I bottle it.  I do that be just extending the time on the yeast post the active ferment phase to be sure.  Usually no problems.